# Should Arqade be divided into sections?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, site-policies, scope

Arqade is a nice site, but it just has too many games on it, so some users might be familiar with some games but not others. Shouldn't it be divided into a section for every genre?

Here are some examples:

- Real time strategy (Starcraft 2, Company of Heroes)
- Rpg (Runescape, Mass Effect)
- First-Person Shooter (Call Of Duty, Destiny)

There are just too many games on Arqade, and users might have to scroll through many pages before they come to anything useful. If all questions for all communities were in one community, wouldn't it be very disorganized and messy? That's what I'm feeling. Should Arqade be divided?

Comment: I think the search and tagging features should help users find what they are looking for

Comment: Genre-specific Stack Exchanges would have too much overlap. If there's anything that could be split into it's own SE community, it would be Minecraft, but despite being the number 1 [most used tag](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags), there still isn't enough activity to sustain an entire site dedicated to it

Comment: @Robotnik Imagine a whole site of Minecraft crash reports... \**shudders**

Comment: @fredley Ugh, no thanks :)

Comment: @Robotnik A whole Arqade without those damn crash reports? Sign me up.

Answer (score 22):

Absolutely not.  Arqade is nowhere near the size of SO, which is the largest site in the network.  If there are too many games, as you state, you can always ignore the tags of those games you don't want to see.

Beside, even if we did this, it would cause more headaches than it would solve, by far.

What would we do with games that cross the boundries?  Spellforce comes to mind; it's both an RPG, and an RTS.

Would each section have its own policies?  Would [identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) be allowed on one or more?  Would [game-recommendation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) be allowed?  Or would they all be under the umbrella of Arqade policies?

---

You haven't even participated on Arqade.  What problem are you attempting to solve here?

Comment: He *would* participate, if only he could find questions about Dengeki Iraira Bou Returns amid all the clutter!

Comment: Borderlands is another great game with a lot of activity, that is both an FPS and an RPG.